# Проблема с доступом к ChatGPT

Tags: dns, vpn, wireguard

Был арендован выделенный сервер в Европе чтобы сделать себе VPN. Настроил я его по гайдам из открытых источников используя WireGuard. При настройке я указывал два DNS – 1.1.1.1 и 8.8.8.8. Все работает все хорошо за исключением одного. Я пользуюсь ChatGPT и при использовании с телефона все работает отлично. При использовании с ноутбука доступ блокируется. Я читал про подобные проблемы у людей, но я не понимаю почему доступ блокируется только с ноутбука? И правильно ли я понимаю что надо использовать другой DNS?

Если это имеет значение то пользуюсь я iPhone и MacBook